# alpha-number floyd triangle

Tags: c

I want an alph-numeric floyd triangle, but it's showing some error.. Maybe a logical error..

The code that i used is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, j;
    char a[11]="ABCDEFGHIJ";
    int n[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int index = 0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(i%2==0)
                printf(" %d ",a[index]);
            else
                printf(" %d ",n[index]);
            index++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However the output I'm getting is:

```
1
66 67
4 5 6
71 72 73 74
```

The output that i want is this:

```
1
B C
4 5 6
G H I J
```

Let me know where am I lacking..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
            printf(" %d ",a[index]);
```

to

```
            printf(" %c ",a[index]);
```

This will format `a[index]` as a character rather than its [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code.

By the way, you don't really need the arrays. You can simply compute the letters and numbers based on `index`:

```
        if(i%2==0)
            printf(" %c ", 'A' + index);
        else
            printf(" %d ", index + 1);
```

Comment: perfect!! How silly of me...
Your trick has shorten my clumsy code.. thanks

Comment: @Ruud ya i was facing the issue of starting it from B.. I already removed it and it worked.. Anyway thanks for the help..